# Emacs codepage problems: Terminus font, utf-8 and cyrillic-translit input

Tags: emacs, utf-8, transliteration

I love the `cyrillic-translit` input method for Emacs. However, after I set the wonderful [Terminus](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/) as my default font, the Russian characters appear in Arial or something (in any case it's not Terminus).

How do I fix this? Setting the default font to UTF-8 (Emacs equivalent `"-outline-Terminus-normal-normal-normal-mono-16-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1"`) doesn't help. I guess this possibly means that Terminus lacks decent UTF-8 support?

Anyhow, I'm using the following snippet for switching between cyrillic-translit input method and the "normal" mode:

```
(defun toggle-cyrillic-input-method ()
  "toggle between French and no input method"
  (interactive)
  (if (string= current-input-method "cyrillic-translit")
      (set-input-method nil)
    (set-input-method "cyrillic-translit")))
(global-set-key [f9] 'toggle-cyrillic-input-method)
```

Now -- is there a way to make the snippet not only switch over to `cyrillic-translit` but also switch the codepage when I press F9?

In other words, how do I make it also toggle the font between `"-outline-Terminus-normal-normal-normal-mono-16-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1"` (Latin) and `"-outline-Terminus-normal-normal-normal-mono-16-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-5"` (Russian)?

It's the only workaround I (as a non-programmer) could think of. Any other ideas are welcome, too. Thanks!